# Show multiple levels of forums / categories in select with only one or two foreach loops

Tags: codeigniter

I have this menu function below that I use to get a list of forums and categories.

Each time i need to get a new level I have to add a foreach loop in the menu function. I would like to be able to only have one or two foreach loops that can get ever level belonging to that forum

> **Question:** How can I Only have one or two foreach loops in my menu
>   function that can get multiple levels of categories

Menu Function

```
public function menu() {
    $html = '';

    $html .= '<select class="form-control">';

    $html .= '<option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>';

    foreach ($this->get_parent_forums() as $parent) {

        if ($parent->pid == '0') {

            $html .= '<option value="" class="optionParent">' . $parent->name . '</option>';

            foreach ($this->get_child_forums($parent->fid) as $childs) {

                if ($childs->pid == $parent->fid) {

                    $html .= '<option value="" class="optionChild">' .$childs->name. '</option>';

                    foreach ($this->get_child_forums($childs->fid) as $grandchilds) {

                        if ($grandchilds->pid == $childs->fid) {

                            $html .= '<option value="" class="optionChild">' .$grandchilds->name. '</option>';

                        }

                    }

                } 

            }

        }

    }

    $html .= '</select>';

    return $html;

}
```

Full Controller Code

```
 <?php

    class Forum_management extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('admin/forum/forum_model');
    }

    public function add() {
        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $this->forum_model->insert();

        }

        $data['forums_select'] = $this->menu();

        $this->load->view('template/forums/forum_add_view', $data);
    }   

    public function menu() {
        $html = '';

        $html .= '<select class="form-control">';

        $html .= '<option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>';

        foreach ($this->get_forums() as $parent) {

            if ($parent->pid == '0') {

                $html .= '<option value="" class="optionParent">' . $parent->name . '</option>';

                foreach ($this->get_child_forums($parent->fid) as $childs) {

                    if ($childs->pid == $parent->fid) {

                        $html .= '<option value="" class="optionChild">' .$childs->name. '</option>';

                        foreach ($this->get_child_forums($childs->fid) as $grandchilds) {

                            if ($grandchilds->pid == $childs->fid) {

                                $html .= '<option value="" class="optionChild">' .$grandchilds->name. '</option>';

                            }

                        }

                    } 

                }

            }

        }

        $html .= '</select>';

        return $html;

    }

    public function get_forums() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('forum');
        $this->db->where('pid', '0');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get_child_forums($fid) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('forum');
        $this->db->where('pid', $fid);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function has_parent($fid) {
        $this->db->select('pid');
        $this->db->from('forum');
        $this->db->where('fid', $fid);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: show your controller method

Comment: @RazibAlMamun added controller at bottom on question

Comment: If understood correctly you want to loop over sub-forums and repeat that step whenever there is another sub-level?

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `option` tag in your `get_forums($pid)` method. I hope it's can helpful for you.

Forum_model.php

```
<?php
public function get_forums($pid) {
    $forums = '';

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('forum');
    $this->db->or_where('pid', $pid);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach($query->result_array() as $result){
        $forums .= '<option value="'.$result['fid'].'" class="optionChild">'.$result['name'].'</option>';
        $this->get_forums($result['fid'])
    }

    return $forums;
}
?>
```

In View Page :

```
<select name="pid" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['fid'];?>" class="optionParent"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
        <?php echo $category['forums']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry did not work I have had to try it another way which gets the categories / forums now but I have to put multiple foreach loops in for every level. I have now updated it with new code that I have tried

Comment: That's the only way could make it work so far. Up voted for your effort

Comment: have added a answer now / solution

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.

I got the idea from here https://gist.github.com/YavorK/5578b4f1b32fe125e0f7eab214270c30

Some small changes for a select option instead of ul. And made library instead.

```
<?php

class Forum_select {

    private $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function generate($name = 'pid') {
        $html = '';

        $html .= '<select name="'.$name.'" class="form-control">';

        $html .= $this->create_option($this->getforums());

        $html .= '</select>';

        return $html;
    }

    function create_option($items, $startingParentId = 0)
    {
        $htmlOutput = '';

        foreach ($items as $item) { 

            if ($item['pid'] != $startingParentId) { 

                continue;
            }

            $htmlOutput .= '<option value="'. $item['fid'] .'">' . $item['name'] . '</option>';
            $htmlOutput .= $this->create_option($items, $item['fid']);
        }


        return $htmlOutput;
    }   

    public function getforums() {
        $this->CI->db->select('*');
        $this->CI->db->from('forum');
        $query = $this->CI->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```